# printing first few characters of a character array?

Tags: c, arrays, printf

Hi i have a simple code which prints three characters of a charater array as shown below

```
void main()
{
    char str[]={65,66,67};
    printf("%.3s",str);
}
```

this gives the output `ABC`,but i was wondering since this is not a string means it is not null terminated then how can `%s` work on it and give the correct result?

Comment: I was actuallt trying to ask if %.3s is because of which it is printing the first three characters?

Comment: @ecatmur:i intentionally did it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you passed the length of the string, no 0 terminator is required by printf.

> 7.21.6.1 - 8
>
> **If the precision  is  speciﬁed**,  no  more  than  that  many bytes  are
>   written. If  the precision is not speciﬁed or is greater than the size
>   of the array, the array shall contain a null character.

Comment: sorry didnt get you ?whats meant by "it happens to find a 0 bytes somewhere in the memory"?

Comment: @haris No, I was wrong, I didn't see the `.3` part, sorry for that.

Comment: To OP, please remember that the number of bytes does not always equal to number of characters. Unicode characters can take up to 2 bytes!

Comment: Thanx...what is this which you have mentioned is it where you got information from "7.21.6.1 - 8"

Comment: The C11 standard draft. Search for n1570.

Answer (score 2):

It works because you supplied a precision modifier. %.3s literally means print first 3 bytes from input. If you were to remove the modifier ("%.3s" -> "%s") this code would still build without error but the runtime results are unpredictable (and welcoming for exploits).

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the answers above (by @cnicutar and dans3itz): the following code prints "ABCDE" i.e. `printf` scans the array to the first null character (0 byte):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char str[]={65,66,67};
    char c = 68; 
    int x = 69; 
    int y = 70; 
    int z = 0;
    int w = 71;
    printf("%s", str);
    return 0;
}
```

`F` (`int w = 71;`) is not printed.

Comment: this is totally wrong what u are telling how could this print ABCDE when str has only three bytes in it...

Comment: @haris, you might want to compile and run, before making smart conclusions. Here is the result on my mac (i686-apple-darwin9-gcc-4.0.1): `user@host:~$ gcc -o test test.c 
user@host:~$ ./test
ABCDE`

Comment: @haris, `str, c, x, y, z, w` are stored on the stack, so `str` points to a memory block which contains `65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 0, 71`. This is why `printf` takes `ABCDE`.

Comment: While fun, this result is probably a bit implementation-specific.

Comment: @NateKohl, sure. I posted that example to explain how `printf` works. Actual results depend on the way local variables are stored in the memory. Or you mean that it depends on the implementation of `printf`. I think it doesn't because the language specification defines that for "%s" the array should contain null character.

Comment: Right, I meant the bit about memory -- it seemed like a good idea to point out that people who try running your example might not get the output that you got.  :)

Answer (score 0):

@khachik I don't think that snippet runs as you expect. I cannot reproduce the result on OS X using either GCC 4.2; 4.7 or Clang 3.1

Comment: this must be a comment, not an answer. The snippet runs as posted. I compiled, ran and posted the code, there were no expectations.

Comment: I lack the rep. to post comments at this time. However, the context of your answer implied an expectation of the execution result. Forgive me if I misinterpreted this. The purpose of this post was to emphasize the unpredictability of that code. Clang 3.1 and GCC produce different results. Additionally, the GCC version produces different results with each execution of the application.

Comment: my answer was to explain what may happen, if "%s" is used for an array without null character at the end. That behavior cannot be considered as expected and therefor must not be used. It is just wrong to pass an array without null terminator with "%s", without precision specifier. I don't know how else I can explain this.